# Disable click link functionality and mask out a table row

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, html-table

I'm trying to implement functionality which when a link is clicked the corresponding anchor table row is effectively blanked out and the link disabled.

Is this possible using jQuery?

An example of one of the table rows would be:-

```
<tr class="bcell">
    <th scope="row"><a title="bla" class="addlink" id="a_205">Adrian&nbsp;Apple</a></th>
    <td>name</td>
    <td class="bcell">
        <span>0&nbsp;/&nbsp;0</span>
    </td>
    <td>jt 76 99 44 D</td>
    <td>12122121212121</td>
</tr>
```

So if the anchor is clicked, the row will be blanked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet will be self-explaining:

```
$(".addlink").click(function(){
  [..]

  //$(this) refers to the clicked anchor
  //With .parents("tr:first") you retrieve
  //the desired anchor row
  var AnchorRow = $(this).parents("tr:first");

  // Now you can do wathever you want: You have the anchor row (It's a JQuery Object)
  // And the anchor link
  [..]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
.show() hide();
```

or

using `.html() or .text()` replace the content itself

or

`addClass and removeClass or add()` for adding css.

What ever you wish .

Comment: Think I'm going to use the idea below to add/remove class from the link and table row.